# how to change order of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example I have a list of li's like this:

```
<li id='r1' class='myclass'>something</li>
<li id='r2' class='myclass'>something</li>
<li id='r3' class='myclass'>something</li>
<li id='r4' class='myclass'>something</li>
<li id='r5' class='myclass'>something</li>
```

I want to use a function for replace two li with each other.

for example: put li2 o first and put li1 on second.

and I have a function like this:

```
function updown(li_id , dir)
{
 //what should i type here....
}
```

li_id: is my li id

dir:    is "up" or "down"

Comment: This is pretty thin, as you're not showing any effort of your own. I would *bet* there is plenty of stuff when Googling, say, `jquery change order of html elements`.

Comment: I have try for that but I didn't see any reason to make my question difficult and complicate.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) As someone who is still fairly new to jQuery, what you're trying to do is not difficult. Put forth some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use before() or after() to swap the order of two element :

```
$('#r1').before($('#r2'));​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/10/)

or your function:

```
function updown(li_id , dir) {
    $('#'+li_id)[dir!='up'?'before':'after']($('#'+li_id)[dir!='up'?'next':'prev']());
}
```

use like:

```
updown('r3', 'up');
updown('r1', 'down');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ua2a/11/)

Comment: yes. next,prev,before,after. but for example there is not any prev li or what can i do with html id conflict

Comment: ID's are unique, there is no ID conflict unless you do a big no-no and create one. As for non existing previous or next element, you can't swap places with something that are'nt there ?

Comment: TNX, It worked. and I also used jquery.sortable. is it supported by old browsers?